# Determine Domain for Lambda inside API Gateway for Firebase "Domain not whitelisted by project"

Tags: aws-lambda, firebase-authentication, aws-api-gateway, whitelist

I have the following setup;

CloudFront -> APIG Origin -> Lambda (express REST API) -> Firebase Auth.

I need to white list the domain, I have added both the APIG URL and CloudFront URLs to the whitelisted domains on Firebase under;

Authentication > Sign-in method > Authorised domains;

I have whitelisted both the CloudFront and APIG URLs and this get the following error;

- *id*.cloudfront.net
- *id*.execute-api.*region*.amazonaws.com

```
Could not generate verification email: 
{
    "code": "auth/unauthorized-continue-uri",
    "message": "Domain not whitelisted by project"
}
```

Domains are registers as shown

[image: registered both APIG and CloudFront URLs]

Question: Why do I still get this error? Do I need to enter the domain for the lambda function its self? If so where do I find this information?

Answer (score 0):

[https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6400741?hl=en#:~:text=To%20use%20Firebase%20Authentication%20in,of%20your%20web%20app's%20hosts](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6400741?hl=en#:%7E:text=To%20use%20Firebase%20Authentication%20in,of%20your%20web%20app%27s%20hosts).

Found the answer, I misunderstood the person of the Domain whitelist. So it's the domain you are redirecting to not coming from.

> To use Firebase Authentication in a web app, you must whitelist the
> domains that the Firebase Authentication servers can redirect to after
> signing in a user. By default, localhost and your Firebase project's
> hosting domain are whitelisted. You must whitelist the full domain
> names of any other of your web app's hosts.